# How to manipulate Message coming from Netty server/client

Tags: java, io, netty

I am prototyping a Netty client/server transfer for strings, now I want to pass these strings to file when it arrives to server side.

Client:

```
    private ClientBootstrap bootstrap;
    private Channel connector;
    private MyHandler handler=new MyHandler();

    public boolean start() {
        // Standard netty bootstrapping stuff.
        Executor bossPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Executor workerPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ChannelFactory factory =
                new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(bossPool, workerPool);
        this.bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);

        // Declared outside to fit under 80 char limit
        final DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder frameDecoder =
                new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                        Delimiters.lineDelimiter());
        this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                return Channels.pipeline(
                        handler,
                        frameDecoder,
                        new StringDecoder(),
                        new StringEncoder());
            }
        });

        ChannelFuture future = this.bootstrap
                .connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 12345));
        if (!future.awaitUninterruptibly().isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("--- CLIENT - Failed to connect to server at " +
                    "localhost:12345.");
            this.bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
            return false;
        }

        this.connector = future.getChannel();
        return this.connector.isConnected();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (this.connector != null) {
            this.connector.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
        }
        this.bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
        System.out.println("--- CLIENT - Stopped.");
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String message) {
        if (this.connector.isConnected()) {
            // Append \n if it's not present, because of the frame delimiter
            if (!message.endsWith("\n")) {
                this.connector.write(message + '\n');
            } else {
                this.connector.write(message);
            }
            System.out.print(message);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Server:

```
    private final String id;
    private ServerBootstrap bootstrap;
    private ChannelGroup channelGroup;
    private MyHandler handler= new MyHandler();


    public Server(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // public methods ---------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean start() {
        // Pretty standard Netty startup stuff...
        // boss/worker executors, channel factory, channel group, pipeline, ...
        Executor bossPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Executor workerPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ChannelFactory factory =
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossPool, workerPool);
        this.bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

        this.channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup(this.id + "-all-channels");


        // declared here to fit under the 80 char limit
        final ChannelHandler delimiter =
                new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                        Delimiters.lineDelimiter());
        this.bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

            @Override
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                SimpleChannelHandler handshakeHandler =
                        new SimpleChannelHandler();
                return Channels.pipeline(
                        handler,
                        delimiter,
                        new StringDecoder(),
                        new StringEncoder(),
                        handshakeHandler);
            }
        });

        Channel acceptor = this.bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(12345));
        if (acceptor.isBound()) {
            System.out.println("+++ SERVER - bound to *:12345");
            this.channelGroup.add(acceptor);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.err.println("+++ SERVER - Failed to bind to *:12345");
            this.bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.channelGroup.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
        this.bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
        System.err.println("+++ SERVER - Stopped.");
    }
```

Handlers used:
Client handler:

```
public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler{
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        if(e.getMessage() instanceof String){
            System.out.println((String)e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

Server handler:

```
@Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        Channel channel= ctx.getChannel();
        channel.write(e.getMessage());
        if(e.getMessage() instanceof String){
            System.out.println((String)e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

client runner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final int nMessages = 5;

        try {
            Client c = new Client();

            if (!c.start()) {
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nMessages; i++) {

                Thread.sleep(1L);
                c.sendMessage((i + 1) + "\n");
            }
            c.stop();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Server Runner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Server s = new Server("server1");

        if (!s.start()) {
            return;
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                s.stop();
            }
        });
    }
```

now what I really need is to print the message that I wrote on the channel on both client and server side and I am really puzzled on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline creation seems to be wrong at first look. At server side when decoding, the `Delimiter` needs to come first, then the `StringDecoder` and then the business handler. You could resolve this probably by just putting breakpoints in these decoders and encoders. Also take a look at this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) for very good documentation on how this works.